# Using PHPExcel and it is not saving xlsx file

Tags: php, phpexcel

We have had this program running for a long time now but for some reason it has suddenly stopped creating the new .xlsx file on the server and just opens the previously created file.
Nothing has changed so we are not sure why this has started happening.

If we remove this line from the bottom of the code we get the echo statement
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', **FILE**));
so it appears that this line is causing the issue.

We run a SQL command to extract the data which we have checked and it is working fine
We then create the entries in the spreadsheet and finally issues these three lines of code to save the file

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
```

It seems like the last line doesn't save to the server

Any help would really be appreciated

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Please show what your last line is

Comment: Are you looking in the same directory as `__FILE__` is?

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your replies

The last line in the code is 
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
and this doesn't seem to save the file.
 
We checked where __FILE__ is pointing and checked but no file is being created there

If we put an echo after the last line the echo isn't displayed
If we remove $objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__)); then we get the echo

Thanks for any help

Rich